# Is there any advantage for a person dying as virgin?

Tags: scripture, dharma, practice

I know staying virgin whole-life really needs good discipline, strong will power et cetera.

But what are Spiritual & Material benefits of being Virgin whole life? Id est, dying as a virgin? Do Hindu scriptures have options on this matter?

Comment: Haha, why you want to be a Virgin? If such question has arisen out of **permanent** Vairagyā then go ahead. Strict celibacy with **mind, speech & body** without any aim to attain divine will make you super human, with the aim to attain divine will `liberate` you. But if this question has arisen out of drama or adventure, shun the idea otherwise you will end up being hypocrite & psychologically pervert at the end.

Comment: Leaving this world during Brahma-chari vrata & following it strictly with study of vedas ,grants one the unity with Brahman itself. I will try to find more about it.

Comment: @DhanrajKumar Why are you posting your private message in the comments too? Don't show it to all other sites. That message is not relevant here.

Comment: It actually depends on what you mean by "virgin"? But just don't spilling seed is not useful. You should convert Veerya into Ojas Shakti which can help you in liberation through Kundalini Yoga.

Comment: Bramhacharya is strong base for the skyscrapper of Sadhna. It purifies you..but Bramhacharya without any further goal is unstable and can make you mad like a Musth elephant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musth or mattagaja in sanskrit.

Comment: "I know staying virgin whole-life really needs good discipline, strong will power et cetera." I disagree as a man staying a virgin is pretty easy. As a woman it is much more difficult.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no advantage in dying a virgin unless one has formally taken up the Sannyasa dharma i.e unless one has ritually become a sannyasi.

For a sannyasi strict celibacy is a must.

But for all other situations dying a virgin is considered as a bad karma.

Because as soon as we are born we obtain the three debts on us : Deva Rina (debt to the Gods), Rishi Rina (debt to the Seers) and the Pitru Rina (debt to the ancestors or the manes). Of which, the Pitru Rina can not be repaid unless  one begets a son.

> 9.106. **Immediately on the birth of his first-born a man is (called) the father of a son and is freed from the debt to the manes**; that
>   (son), therefore, is worthy (to receive) the whole estate.
>
> 9.107. **That son alone on whom he throws his debt and through whom he obtains immortality**, is begotten for (the fulfilment of) the law; all
>   the rest they consider the offspring of desire.
>
> **Manu Smriti.**
>
> If a father sees the face of a' living son born, he is Freed from the
>   debt [he owes to his ancestors] and attains to immortality. (53) **With
>   the very birth of a son, a father is freed from his ancestral debt and
>   attains to purification on that Very day, for he (i.e., the son)
>   liberates him from the hell. (54)**
>
> **Atri Smriti Chapter 1.**

Not repaying any of the three debts is an offence as stated in the following verse:

> Manu Smriti 6.35. When he has paid the three debts, let him apply his
>   mind to (the attainment of) final liberation; **he who seeks it without
>   having paid (his debts) sinks downwards**

So, in all cases clearing the debts is a must and the first priority. And if one is a life long virgin that is not possible.

Also as per [the book "essence of dharma sindhu"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php) chirakAla bramachArya is prohibited in this age that is in Kali Yuga.

> **Kali Yuga Nishiddhas**:
>
> The following are the avoidable and unnecessary acts of Kali Yuga viz.
>   Samudra Yatra, carrying of Kamandulu to misdirect the Public ,
>   remarriages, begetting children from husband’s brothers; Go Vadha;
>   Mamsa Bhakshana at Shraddhas; performing vivaha to a physically immature girl; **Chira kaala Brahmacharitwa**; Naramedha Ashwamedha Gomedha
>   Yagna; Madya Paana, Abhakshya Bhakshana, Apeya paana, Agamyaagamana
>   orcwandering aimlesly Rahasya Prayascittha, Devata Puja and Pashubali
>   for evil ends; Kula Bhrashtata; Extreme Profiteering and narrow
>   mindedness.

Comment: But most of people dying as virgin so soul will be gone to hanuman who is also virgin god.

Comment: @DhanrajKumar Oh is it so? Where did u hear about it? I have never heard anything like that.

Comment: Nice Answer. BTW What do you think about Devata puja is also added in avoidables.In the contrary we see more & more people engaging in devata puja in kali-yuga.Or it's just referring to avoid idol worship?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks. And no devata puja is not prohibited. **Devata puja for evil ends** is what is prohibited. Similarly pashubali for evil ends is also prohibited.

Comment: @TheHawk Hanuman had a son, Makaradhwaja, born from his sweat (swēdaja putra). He has therefore fulfilled his pitṛṛṇa.

Answer (score 5):

Lifelong celibacy is not mandatory, but it is allowed, at least for Brahmanas, and it confers great benefits.  Here is what [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu02.htm) the Manu Smriti says:

> 243. But if (a student) desires to pass his whole life in the teacher's house, he must diligently serve him, until he is freed from this body.
> 244. A Brahmana who serves his teacher till the dissolution of his body, reaches forthwith the eternal mansion of Brahman.
> 245. He who knows the sacred law must not present any gift to his teacher before (the Samavartana); but when, with the permission of his teacher, he is about to take the (final) bath, let him procure (a present) for the venerable man according to his ability,
> 246. (Viz.) a field, gold, a cow, a horse, a parasol and shoes, a seat, grain, (even) vegetables, (and thus) give pleasure to his teacher.
> 247. (A perpetual student) must, if his teacher dies, serve his son (provided he be) endowed with good qualities, or his widow, or his Sapinda, in the same manner as the teacher.
> 248. Should none of these be alive, he must serve the sacred fire, standing (by day) and sitting (during the night), and thus finish his life.
> 249. A Brahmana who thus passes his life as a student without breaking his vow, reaches (after death) the highest abode and will not be born again in this world.