# What are the benefits of following Brahmcharya?

Tags: marriage, sex

What are the benefits of following Brahmcharya ? What is mentioned about it in scriptures ?

Comment: There are no benefits in following life-long brahmacharya unless you are a sannyasin; in fact, grihasthasramis are expected to produce virtuous children. See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18551/is-there-any-advantage-for-a-person-dying-as-virgin

Answer (score 1):

In yogic and especially Shivam Tantric schools Brahmacharyam is one of the limbs in Yoga which is very similar to Patanjali's 8 limb Yoga. The list is mentioned as a part of Saura Puranam. In performing Brahmacaryam, especially by Males, results in retaining their Tejus which convert into Ojas. A similar concept is also given in the Shaktism school for women. Similar phenomenon also happens with Ghee (Clarified Butter) from a specific breed of cows, which is preserved in the Earth (underground) for over a century. This approach is discussed in Ayurveda as well. Ojas is a type of radiance that envelopes each cell of the body. There is no similar term in English for this, but many use the term, Ora. If one might notice, Shiva, Krisha, and Devi are depicted with certain Ora enveloping them, it a very vague approach of depiction yet the intent is clear. Yoga is tightly coupled with Ayurveda, they go hand in hand. It's stated clearly in both these schools that the last Dhatus (elements with which a physical body is constructed) is Tejus (Semen), hence exhausting it frequency will result in putting a strain upon the body which in turn becomes an impediment to Yogic lifestyle. The purpose of Male Tajus is not to trash it for pleasure, but for the progeny (creating a new life). Nature's association of pleasure with its exhaustion is to create a conducive and inviting experience towards creating new life. Assume if this experience was very painful and awkward, the driving force towards life-making would have been put away by many. This topic is common across all Schools of Sanatana Culture and is also included in Buddhism and Jainism.