# What is Pitri-Rina ? How to get rid of it? Why some people say that having a son is mandatory?

Tags: pitru

What is Pitri-Rina ? How to get rid of it ? What are the details about Pitri-Rina ?

Many people say that [having a son is mandatory to get rid of Pitri-Rina.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18580/23709) But in modern history lots of people who were highly spiritual persons remained unmarried eg- Adi Shankaracharya . I think many of the present Shankaracharya are also unmarried. Most spiritual persons now a days don't marry .
And I am sure they must be well versed in the scriptures . Why don't they get married ?

Was this rule of having a son not applicable in Kaliyuga ?

Because upto Dwapar Yuga ,world was completely different from Kaliyug. People would literally see their ancestors in heaven. Visits of gods like Indra was normal. World was completely different from now.

Comment: there are 3 debts we take when deciding to take birth as human - debt to devas, to rishis and to pitrus. devas give us air,water,food etc. so we pay back via puja. rishis give us vedas, shastras etc. so we pay back via reading scripture and brahmacharya. pitrus give us birth and raise us, so we pay back by tarpan/sraddh and give them chance to be born back again by having sons.

Comment: @mar , What is born back again ? Couldn't understand it.

Comment: what do u think pitrus will do after their stay in pitru lok is over and they have to take human birth again ? wouldn't they prefer to be born in the same family ?

Comment: @mar Are people often born into the same family, in a later generation ? I’ve wonder this. Maybe I should post as a proper question on here.

Comment: Ok I posted asking as part of a larger question on jivas & karma & such stuffs : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54074/is-the-jiva-who-harms-you-the-same-jiva-you-did-something-bad-to-them-in-past-li

Comment: not necessarily. but not unlikely either.

Comment: @mar I see, thx ! Didn’t see this reply till right now. But yeah that sounds right. I think karma is so complicated that it will happen in many many different ways in numerous multitudes situations 