# Is The Jiva Who Harms You The Same Jiva You Did Something Bad To Them In Past Life?

Tags: karma, jiva

I’ve googled many many times & read through the karma tag on here (twice!) & still couldn’t work this out.

I’ve heard thousands & thousands of times, an Indian Hindu person saying “From what past life this moron have come from to get some kinda revenge?”

I thought there are tons of universes, tons of jivas, we can be born anywhere.

& if someone is bad to us, hurts us, it can be anyone, doesn’t have to someone we knew before and did something bad to them.

Maybe this is not accurate.

So my question: Is it the same jiva harms us that we harmed them in past life ?

Reading mar’s comment on river’s post about pitr rin also, that sometimes jiva are born back into same family, just in a later generation ?

Does this happen a lot, do Hindu texts say this ?

That karm-phal given in same family often, in next generations ?

Thx for any info guys

Comment: Yes,Karma can occur between two individual jivas only if there is some bondage of debt(rnanubandhana) between them.If i steal something from you in this lifetime the opportunity for me to steal can only arise if there some debt b/w you and me i.e you owe me something.Your past actions created such attitude in me and impelled me to take such a step.

Comment: Thx @Rāmachandra Ok so I’m assuming the person who harms us is often someone we harmed before. That makes sense. Can it also be that sometimes we are harmed by a person where we never knew them in a past life ? Like they were sent to punish us for something we did, but we did it to someone else altogether ?